# Как бы вы переформулировали фразу " он не такой, как все, а такой, как ты"

Tags: фразеология

Как бы вы переформулировали фразу "он не такой, как все, а такой, как ты" ? 
Желательно, оставить сочетание "не такой"

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу необходимости что-то тут переформулировывать. Нормальная фраза, нормально звучит.

Answer (score 1):

В контексте возражения на утверждение "он такой, как все" исходная реплика с дублированием выражения вполне уместна (отрицание сказанного оппонентом и возражение его же словами).
Если же это самостоятельное утверждение с противопоставлением, вроде упрёка мужу о его влиянии на сына, то повторение собственного выражения менее обоснованно (похоже на возражение самому себе), и реплику (в адрес мужа или влиятельного недруга) можно переформулировать так:

> Он не такой, как все - (он) весь в тебя!